# What does the letter on the Oracle release mean?

Tags: oracle

What does the letter on the Oracle release mean?

Comment: What letter? Can you privide at least a link?

Comment: Try this [link](http://www.oraclebrains.com/2006/12/understanding-oracle-release-number-format/) and [this](http://home.c2i.net/toreingolf/oracle/versions.htm) one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I Assume your referring to the i or g They stand for internet and grid. I personally think they are Mainly there for marketing purposes rather than any particular technology reason.

Comment: That's what I meant. I was curious about the i and g. For instance, 9i and 10g

Comment: Personally, I expect the next major release to be 12c for "cloud".

Comment: I wonder if this happens to Java and MySQL now, too ;-)

Comment: They are there purely for marketing, apparently, it was "10i" right up to about a week before announcement, when suddenly it became "10g"

Comment: @JonEricson You deserve a cookie!